# asp.net mvc foreach many to many filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My code in view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model._games)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>

            <td>
                @foreach (var item2 in Model._days.Where(x => x.Games.Any(u=> u.Id == item.Id)))
                {
                    @item2.CutOffTime;
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

What is the proper way to show second foreach and filter it like I do? If I do not filter(using only `Model._days`, It shows all Days, but when I use Where filter with ID as you can see in second foreach, it doesn't show anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues:
1. You're using deferred loading and forgot to populate `.Games` property of `Model._days` by using of `Include` method (EF) or `LoadWith` (LINQ 2 SQL)
2. Games is empty
3. Games is not empty but you've set an incorrect filter
4. You've populated either `Model._games` or `Model._days.Games` with incorrect data

Troubleshooting: set a breakpoint at the second `foreach` and see what actual values do you have in both collections.

Comment: in second collection i do not get anything as i said.. in first collection values are proper. in second collection values are proper if i do not filter.. which means that filter is wrong.. that is the reason i asked.

Comment: @JohnMathilda i can' guess what you have in u.id and item.id . If there are matching ones, the inner foreach MUST will iterate, not possible other way.

Answer (score 0):

- Change your second foreach to

  ```
   @foreach (var item2 in Model._days)
   {
     if(item2.Games.select(e=>e.Id).Cotains(item.Id)
    {
       @item2.CutOffTime;
    }
   }
  ```

Comment: Gives errro `CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'bool' because 'bool' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`